# Messianic Jew and Wine

Tags: halacha, synagogue, avodah-zarah, christianity, grapes-wine

At what stage does a born-Jewish messianic Jew's presence at and/ or participation in an Orthodox synagogue's kiddush make wine 'Yayin Nesech'?

Comment: assuming the yayin is non-mevushal I presume?

Answer (score 7):

Wine becomes *yayin nesech* when it is open and then is handled by a non-Jew or by a Jew who violates Shabbat or participates in *avoda zara*. "Messianic Judaism" could certainly be considered a form of *avoda zara* as discussed in other places on this site. So if the person touches an open bottle of wine, that wine would become prohibited.

If the wine is *mevushal*, though, there is no issue of *yayin nesech* because the wine is not considered fit for *avoda zara* libations. My experience is that most *shuls* use wine that is *mevushal* to get around the problem of someone attending *kiddush* who does not keep *shabbat*. Therefore, I would assume that your *shul* probably is also using *mevushal* wine and there is no problem.  This is easy to check by looking at the label of the bottle.

Comment: touching the bottle is not sufficient. they have to move the wine

Answer (score -1):

You are all incorrect. Wine only becomes nesech when used for a ritual in the name of an  avoda Zara. However when a goy moves the wine it becomes yayin stam. There is a HUGE difference, yayin nesech is assure b'hana (forbidden to derive benefit), and nesech is forbidden on a biblical level. Yayin stam is a rabbinic ordinance but the prohibition  only forbade consumption of the wine, however the rabbinate never forbade stam for benefit.

Comment: The Rema says that one should not derive benefit from yayin stam.

Comment: Gemara avoda Zara says that ALL ameraim admit that you can derive benefit from yayin stam! And please show me where the Rema says that

Comment: Yoreh De'ah 123:1 the Rema says lechatchila one should not derive benefit from Yayin stam. He is lenient in the case of great financial loss.

Comment: Your right, but it doesn't fit with the Gemara, the lashon in the Gemara seems to be lechatchila it's ok.

Comment: This is a question of halacha lma'aseh. Not just what it says in the gemara

Comment: I know it's lmaseh but if ALL the ameraim agree one can get Hanaah from yayin stam, then the later rishonim should pasken like that. Shouldn't they?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: Well why don't they? They aren't allowed to argue on them. And why should we be more stringent than them?

Comment: Tzaddik, you oversimplify the issue. Correct, it's a matter of Maga Akum which is DeRabbanan, not Yayin Nesech DeOraita, but that doesn't mean it's automatically muttar to benefit from..

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't a "Messianic Jew" be actively be participating in idolatry, therefore there use of wine in any regards be for idolatry thus no longer be kosher? Maybe I am thinking too much into this but would venture to guess that anyone practicing idolatry would make kosher wine non kosher once touched.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Charles. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See particularly the focus on sources as an important part in answers. Great to have you learn with us!